# How can I solve this formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importhtml, google-finance

`=index(importhtml(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/";A6;"/key-statistics?p="A6";"EN_US");1;2)`

A6 is tiker: MO

I need Dividend date: Oct 10, 2022

Original link: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MO/key-statistics?p=MO

I have a different formula but it only shows me the ex date dividend: =to_date(index(importhtml(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/";A11);"table";2);7;2)). I want to replace **https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/**  with this from statistics tab.

**https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MO/key-statistics?p=MO**

Comment: How can I change my formula to show me the dividend date imported from yahoo finance link with reference cell A6 where is tiker (MO) ?

Comment: Welcome to [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).  Please note this is not a code writing service. See [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  In particular, have you thoroughly searched for an answer and made attempts to solve this before asking? You haven't shared any research or told us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.  Demonstrate  the  effort you've invested trying to solve this and you are more likely to get experienced members to invest their own time for you. .

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.  Please continue to put all important information in the question not the comments.  You can remove any comments that are no longer relevant. I will take another look at it shortly to see if I can assist.

Comment: Related (StackOverfow): [Yahoo finance historical close price to google sheets returns n/a for close later than 100 days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637966/1330560). "not possible because yahoo site uses JavaScript element - the infinity scroll - which kicks in after 100th value and that's the reason why you can't get past that point. " Note: there is a workaround mentioned on that same question.